# type of identifier does not agree with its usage

Tags: vhdl

I've next structural VHDL definition of ROM memory. When I try to complie it I'm getting "VHDL error at rom_4x4_structural.vhd(13): type of identifier "q" does not agree with its usage as "std_logic" type" error. Can anybody explain me the reason behind that problem?

```
LIBRARY ieee; USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
LIBRARY lpm; USE lpm.lpm_components.all;

ENTITY rom_4x4_structural IS
   PORT(address : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        q       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0));
END rom_4x4_structural;

ARCHITECTURE rom_4x4_structural_arch OF rom_4x4_structural IS
BEGIN
    inst_1: LPM_ROM
    GENERIC MAP (LPM_WIDTH=>4, LPM_WIDTHAD=>4, LPM_FILE=>"rom_4x4_structural.mif")
    PORT MAP (address, q);
END rom_4x4_structural_arch;
```

Comment: The entity or component declaration for LPM_ROM answers that. And named association would probably make the error easier to spot. As it is, I don't believe this even compiled that far as the instatniation is neither direct instantiation nor has a component declaration.

Comment: @BrianDrummond so do I need to declare component or what? And it actually do compile that far.

Comment: You don't have to declare a component. See the syntax for "direct entity instantiation" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Package lpm_components provides a component declaration for lpm_rom with `q` as the last interface object in the port declaration:

```
port (address : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(lpm_widthad-1 downto 0);
              inclock : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
              outclock : in STD_LOGIC := '0';
              memenab : in STD_LOGIC := '1';
              q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(lpm_width-1 downto 0));
```

The problem you are encountering comes from positional association  which is done in order, and q doesn't match the type of the second interface object declaration.

With positional association `q1 would be associated with`inclock`
which has a type std_logic and hence the reference in the error message.

Instead of positional association use named association:

```
PORT MAP (address => address, q => q);
```

The remaining port of mode **in** have default values supplied (and you're apparently not using a clocked ROM and don't need an enable).

You could use both position and named association because `address` is the first port:

```
PORT MAP (address, q => q);
```

See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.1 General.

There's also the reserved word **open** which when used as the actual in an association element can preserve position:

```
PORT MAP (address, open, open, open, q); -- inclock, outclock, memenab unconnected
```

**Following your comment:**

> I see next paragraph: **Totally asynchronous memory operations occur when neither inclock nor outclock is connected. The output q[] is asynchronous and reflects the data in the memory to which address[] points.** So how can I declare it not connected?

See 6.5.6.3 Port clauses, paragraph 8:

> If a formal port is associated with an actual port, signal, or expression, then the formal port is said to be *connected*. If a formal port is instead associated with the reserved word **open**, then the formal is said to be *unconnected*. It is an error if a port of mode **in** is unconnected (see 6.5.6.3) or unassociated (see 6.5.7.3) unless its declaration includes a default expression (see 6.5.2). It is an error if a port of any mode other than **in** is unconnected or unassociated and its type is an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type. It is an error if some of the subelements of a composite formal port are connected and others are either unconnected or unassociated.

In this case the effects of being unassociated or unconnected are the same, there are default expressions providing default values for `inclock,`outclock`and`memenab`.